# Reading json text file fails parsing. Is ostringstream doing something to it?

Tags: c++, json, parsing

I read a text file (.json) that contains this:

```
{ "a" : true }
```

I read the file using:

```
std::ifstream fileStream;
fileStream.open(configFilePath,std::ios::in);
std::ostringstream sstr;
sstr << fileStream.rdbuf();
std::string text = sstr.str();
fileStream.close();
```

If I print the contents, I get the correct text in the output.

The json parser I have (taken from here: https://github.com/sheredom/json.h) fails to try to parse the file.

If I set the string by hand:

```
std::string text = "{\"a\" : true }";
```

The parser works.

What is ostringstream + ifstream doing to the format or contents of the file to make the parsing fail?

[EDIT]

As a user suggests I compared both strings and they were different.
When printing with  "cat -A" I get all the hidden characters.

The first one is the file contents. Second is the string created by hand in the code:

```
File opened. Reading...$
M-oM-;M-?{"a":true}^M$
$
{"a":true}$
```

The file contains 15 characters
The text contains just 10.

To print the first line I use:
_logFile << "File opened. Reading..." << std::endl << std::flush;

So my question is... Why are ifstream + ofstringstream adding those?

Comment: What error does it fail with?

Comment: You'll be glad to hear you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for. It runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Comment: `If I print the contents, I get the correct text in the output.` there might still be some invisible characters in the text file that might not be printed, cause the parsing of the string to fail.

Comment: At a guess I would say, nothing, and that your problems are caused by some issue that isn't apparent from what you've posted here. Instead of printing the strings why don't you put both strings in two different variables and compare them for equality. That should help narrow down the problem (or learn to use your debugger as already suggested).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik . Haha. Yes. I know, I have been programming for many years. I didn't mention that I'm in Linux, this is inside a .so library and I can't attach the IDE to the code for some weird error I'm having. So I'm trying to figure this out myself.

Comment: @john Oh. that's a good idea. Also, another user suggests finding "hidden" items. But anyway, my original question prevails: In case that's happening, why?

Comment: @JohnKugelman no error. It's another app using this library, and the error shows a "funlockfile", which in this case means... "whatever error"

Comment: @darkgaze Well before I start speculating I'd like to know whether the two strings are identical or not, you are assuming that they are not but I would like to be sure.

Comment: @t.niese I updated the question with the results. Seems like it's something related to this. But why?

Comment: That is the UTF8 BOM. I suspect the input file was created with some editor that added encoding information to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error thanks to the comments of the users.

The file was saved in an Utf-8 encoding with BOM, adding symbols not printed in console, magic numbers that tell the editor that the document is encoded as utf-8.

To print hidden symbols in Linux:

```
cat filename.json -A
```

You can save the file without BOM or change the encoding of the file to ascii in case you don't want utf-8:

```
iconv -c -f utf-8 -t ascii -o out.txt in.txt
```

(from utf-8 to ascii, -c ignores invalid characters)

Comment: You don't need to convert it to ascii. You can still use utf-8, you just need to ensure that you save it as utf-8 without BOM (or detect that the BOM exists and remove it yourself). You actually should store it as utf-8 because the library expects `src` to be utf-8 encoded. (`src - a utf-8 json string to parse.`)

Comment: `generating weird hidden` those are not weird hidden symbols, those are magic numbers that tell the editor that the document is encoded as utf-8.

Comment: @t.niese Ok. Understood, but I'm not the one saving the file so I'll have to add checks. Also, I didn't want to get too technical, but I added your comments in the response. Thanks